# interfaceOrientation iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm doing my version app for iPhone, iPhone pro version in the app only works on vision "Portrait" version but it will be the iPad Landscape vision, look what I've done so far:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
else{
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

it detects whether iPhone and if it is, will be in Landscape in any position is that the iPad, iPhone pro is the opposite.

I have not succeeded, did not work.

someone already did something similar? Basically what I want is simple, iPhone == Portrait, iPad == Landscape;

---

I tried to implement in my project but still always with the view in portrait mode on both the iphone and ipad,

I get this error in debug:

> The view controller  returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.

Comment: I do not ... My application is a radio player to browse the app store by JP Floripa, you can see an example of how I want you, the iPhone == Portrait and iPad == Landscape,

I do not know if they are two separate applications or universal
I do not know if they are two separate apps or universal.

Comment: That's not true. I have apps that support only landscape orientation. The key is supporting both landscape modes, left and right. And this both ways rule does not apply for portrait mode. I have many apps that support only regular portrait orientation, but not upsidedown.

Comment: but what about my code? Does anyone have any tips on how to do?

iPhone == Portrait, iPad == LandsCape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    } else {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
}
```

works fine for me!